# Replace multiline string with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file that's basically an INI/CFG file the looks like this:

```
[thing-a]
attribute1=foo
attribute2=bar
attribute3=foobar
attribute4=barfoo

[thing-b]
attribute1=dog
attribute3=foofoo
attribute4=castles

[thing-c]
attribute1=foo
attribute4=barfoo

[thing-d]
attribute1=123455
attribute2=dogs
attribute3=biscuits
attribute4=1234
```

Each 'thing' has a set of attributes that could include all the same ones or a subset there of.

I am trying to write a small bash script that will replace the attributes for 'thing-c' with a predefined block $a1, $a2 & $a3 are generated elsewhere in the wider script:

```
NEW_BLOCK="[thing-c]
attribute1=${a1}
attribute2=${a2}
attribute3=${a3}"
```

I can find the right block with sed like this:

```
THING_BLOCK=$(sed -nr "/^\[thing-c\]/ { :l /^\s*[^#].*/ p; n; /^\[/ q; b l; }" ./myThingFile)
```

I'm not sure if i've gone down a rabbit hole or what with this and I'm pretty sure there is a better way of doing it.

I'm wanting to do what is:

```
sed "s/${THING_BLOCK}/${NEW_BLOCK}/"
```

But I can't quite figure out the multiline aspect to this and I'm not sure what the best route to take is.

Is there a way to do this sort of multiline find and replace with sed (or a better way with bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this sort of multiline find and replace ...

Yes there is indeed a better way, albeit using `awk`:

```
awk -v blk="$NEW_BLOCK" -v RS= '{ORS = RT} $1 == "[thing-c]" {$0 = blk} 1' file
```

Using `-v RS=` we use an empty record separator that splits records in input file on each new line.

Comment: That's wonderful, awk has always seemed like one of those tools that I really ought to learn but never had a specific need to.

This has solved my problem in a much tider method that I thought was going to be possible. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another awk. Store the replacement to `file2` and:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '
NR==FNR {
    b=$0
    next
}
$1~/thing-c/ {
    $0=b
}
{
    print (++c==1?"":ORS) $0
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
[thing-a]
attribute1=foo
attribute2=bar
attribute3=foobar
attribute4=barfoo

[thing-b]
attribute1=dog
attribute3=foofoo
attribute4=castles

[thing-c]
attribute1=${a1}
attribute2=${a2}
attribute3=${a3}

[thing-d]
attribute1=123455
attribute2=dogs
attribute3=biscuits
attribute4=1234
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use `sed`(IMHO `awk` is better here), you must have "nice" data (no special characters that `sed` will try to handle and `[` inside block `thing-3`).
I tested with

```
read -d '' -r NEW_BLOCK <<END
[thing-c]
attribute1=${a1}
attribute2=${a2}
attribute3=${a3}
END
```

For my solution I first need to replace newlines in `$NEW_BLOCK` with the two characters `\n`.

```
echo "This is the replacement string: ${NEW_BLOCK//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

With the "multi-line" option "-z" you can do

```
sed -rz "s/\[thing-c\][^[]*/${NEW_BLOCK//$'\n'/\\n}\n\n/" myThingFile
```

Comment: This also seems to work, as you point out awk is probably the better tool for the job and @anubhava 's solution fits in easier with the wider script.

Thank you for posting another valid solution to my problem.